# How to add Leaflet controls in an outer div

Tags: leaflet

What is wrong with this code ?

```
var mapbuttons_div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'mapbuttons leaflet-bar leaflet-control');
var zoom = L.control.zoom(
    {
        position: 'topleft'
    }
);

mapbuttons_div.appendChild(zoom.getContainer()); // error
```

I want to add the zoom buttons `div` to an outer `div` called `mapbuttons`. But I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that for the container to be created, first you have to add the `control` to the map.

```
var mapbuttons_div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'mapbuttons leaflet-bar leaflet-control');
var zoom = L.control.zoom(
    {
        position: 'topleft'
     }
);

zoom.addTo(map);
mapbuttons_div.appendChild(zoom.getContainer()); // works
```